# How to connect to the Internet through a proxy?

Tags: proxy

I have written below code to access a web page and run in Ubuntu.

How do I fix this? I have tried suggested fixes from all over the internet, but still can't figure out a solution.

Comment: change this to http://www.example.com/index.html and it should work

Answer (score 2):

A `407` response means "Proxy Authentication Required", as described [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.8).

Now you appear to be setting a proxy user and password in the System properties, but it is apparently not working.  I can think of a couple of explanations:

- You could be setting the properties too late.  Those properties are read by the default `ProxySelector` and `Authenticator` as they are initializing.  If you set them too late, then they won't be respected.  Try setting the properties using `-D...` options.
- You could be using the wrong proxy username and password.
- The proxy could be expecting the proxy authentication details in a different form than they are being supplied.  Take a look at the headers in the response for the failed request.  There should be a "Proxy-Authenticate" header that includes a "challenge".

---

If this approach doesn't work, another alternative would be to implement the proxy selection and authentication programatically by implementing and registering your own `ProxySelector` and `Authenticator` classes.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

> I included the ProxyAuthenticator class and now, "java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many times (20)" is thrown.

Somehow, your application has gotten into a redirection loop.

I'm still not convinced that you set the proxy properties early enough.

Comment: @user2699073 - Like I told you in my Answer.  Use the -D... command line option.  (Read the `java` manual entry.  It is explained there.)

Comment: @user2699073 - Try using Wireshark (or equivalent) to look at what is in the HTTP requests and replies.  That should tell you if the requests are going to the right place, what the requests and replies actually contain, and (for the replies) what you are being redirected too.